# Using class's method can be making instance in RUBY?

Tags: ruby

I'm wondering what means 'making instance' in ruby.
I wrote 2 sample codes.
I learned # 1 makes class' instance,

```
# 1.
now = Time.now
# this makes instance


# 2.
if Time.now.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') > '2022/12/19'
  # blabla
end
```

But in case # 2, using Time class' method can be equal to 'making instance'?

Or in this case, it is just "using class' method"?

Comment: Why can't it be both? A function (in general, not just class methods but all functions) is free to do what it wants. That includes making instances of the class, making instances of *other* classes, reading files, accessing the Internet, controlling military spy satellites, etc., etc.

Comment: The expression, "making instance" is one that I've never heard. Learning Ruby will be no more difficult--probably easier--if you can simply forget it.

Comment: I agree with @CarySwoveland the phrase: "making instance" has no real meaning. Everything is an instance in ruby.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confused about class methods and instance methods.

`Time.now` is a class method, and returns an instance of `Time`.

`Time#strftime` is an instance method of the `Time` class, which formats the instance's time.

`Time.now.strftime(...)` first calls `Time.now` which returns an instance of `Time`, then calls that instance's `strftime` method, to format the time into a string.

A class method can return anything, so of course it can return an instance of that class.

E.g.

```rb
class Foo
  def self.return_an_instance
    self.new
  end
  
  def return_three
    3
  end
end

p Foo
# Foo (the class)

p Foo.return_an_instance
# #<Foo:0x196a> (some instance of the class)

p Foo.return_an_instance.return_three
# 3 (return value of instance method)
```